# Отсортировать массив в JAVA (цифры + текст)

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Как отсортировать массив по числам, которые идут перед URl? Допустим, есть данные:

```java
String a[] = {"3 badoo.com", "1 google.com", "70 stackoverflow.com", "14 vk.com"}
```

Чтобы после сортировки стало:

```java
String a[] = {"1 google.com", "3 badoo.com", "14 vk.com", "70 stackoverflow.com"}
```

Comment: Вы можете придумать костыль. Вопрос - зачем. Цифра остается цифрой, а url - это url. Откуда эти данные? Если вы сами сливаете цифру и url в строку, то заканчивайте с этим. Если это даность свыше, то всегда можно распарсить. Создайте класс. Сделайте 2 поля. Положите экземпляры класса в массив либо коллекцию и с помощью компараторов управляйте процессом сортировки. Причем для класса можно создать несколько компараторов, т.е. в зависимости от ситуации вы сможете отсортировать эти данные по разному. Просто в вашем случае это строка и сортироваться она будет по правилам строки...

Answer (score 3):

Парсить строку и задать собственный компаратор:

```
//метод, который вытаскивает из строки число
static Integer extractNumber(String s) {
    //считаем что строка начинается с числа и после числа идет пробел
    return Integer.valueOf(s.split(" ")[0]);
}

//сортировка
Arrays.sort(a, (String s1, String s2) -> extractNumber(s1).compareTo(extractNumber(s2)));
```

Как @Дмитрий уже написал в комментариях: то, что числа и адреса слеплены в строку выглядит неопрятно. При изменении формата придется искать по коду вручную прописанные индексы, сложно добавить обработку ошибок. При добавлении полей разбор строк может разрастись и пустить метастазы по коду. Т.ч. в долгосрочной перспективе имеет смысл создать для хранения информации класс с отдельными полями.

Answer (score 2):

Вот более **ОО** решение. Для конвертации строк в список объектов я использовал стримы. Класс наследует интерфейс `Comparable` для возможности сортировки без использования отдельного `Comparator`'a и является `Immutable`(разницу между `Immutable` vs `Mutable` можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects))

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a[] = { "3 badoo.com", "1 google.com", "70 stackoverflow.com", "14 vk.com" };

    List<IndexedURL> indexedURLs = Stream.of(a).map(IndexedURL::getInstance).collect(Collectors.toList());
    Collections.sort(indexedURLs);

    System.out.println(indexedURLs);

    }
}

final class IndexedURL implements Comparable<IndexedURL> {

    public final int index;
    public final String url; // или даже URL класс

    public IndexedURL(int index, String url) {
        this.index = index;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public int getIndex() {
        return index;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public static IndexedURL getInstance(String obj) {
       String[] split = obj.split(" ");
        try {
            if (split.length == 2) {
                return new IndexedURL(Integer.parseInt(split[0]), split[1]);
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cant parse obj from String :" + obj);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(IndexedURL o) {
        return Integer.compare(this.getIndex(), o.getIndex());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "IndexedURL [index=" + index + ", url=" + url + "]";
    }

    // eq and hash code
```

}

Также необходимо реализовать методы `equals` и `hashCode` для корректного использования объектов в коллекциях [ссылка](http://info.javarush.ru/Coder/2015/09/23/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2-equals-%D0%B8-hashCode-%D0%B2-Java.html)

Answer (score 0):

Для сортировки массива объектов применяем метод [`Arrays.sort(T[],Comparator)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator)):

```java
String[] arr =
{"3 badoo.com", "1 google.com", "70 stackoverflow.com", "14 vk.com"};

// сравниваем строки по порядку
// следования символов
Arrays.sort(arr);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [1 google.com, 14 vk.com, 3 badoo.com, 70 stackoverflow.com]

// получаем число с начала строки до первой
// группы пробельных символов и сравниваем числа
Arrays.sort(arr, Comparator.comparing(str ->
        Integer.parseInt(str.split("\\s+")[0])));

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
// [1 google.com, 3 badoo.com, 14 vk.com, 70 stackoverflow.com]
```